# Java Threads , Print 1 character per second with no order

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to print these threads 1 character per second with no order. If I put in sleep then it becomes in order. How do I make it not in order and print 1 character (any) per second.

```
public class Number1{    
    public static void main(String[] args){

        try{
        Thread a = new Thread(new thread1("A"));
        Thread b = new Thread(new thread1("B"));
        Thread c = new Thread(new thread1("C"));
        a.start();
        b.start();
        c.start();
        a.join(1000);
        b.join(1000);
        c.join(1000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }


    }
}

class thread1 implements Runnable{

    String character;


    public thread1(String a){
        this.character = a;
    }

    public void run(){
            for(int i = 1;i<21;i++)
            {           
            System.out.println("No."+i+" Thread: "+character);
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thread.sleep() is a method which will make your thread to sleep for 1 second and continue. You are using the method join. So change it to thread.sleep(1000

```
    public class Number1{    
    public static void main(String[] args){

        try{
        Thread a = new Thread(new thread1("A"));
        Thread b = new Thread(new thread1("B"));
        Thread c = new Thread(new thread1("C"));
        a.start();
        b.start();
        c.start();
        a.join(1000);
        b.join(1000);
        c.join(1000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }


    }
}

class thread1 implements Runnable{

    String character;


    public thread1(String a){
        this.character = a;
    }

    public void run(){
            for(int i = 1;i<21;i++)
             {           
               Thread.sleep(1000);// This will make the current thread sleep for 1 second  
           System.out.println("No."+i+" Thread: "+character);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i did that and removed .join() then it prints three character per second. I want it to print 1 character(thread) per second in a random order.

Answer (score 0):

I added a sleep to the for loop in your code and it seems to be working.

> No.1 Thread: C 
>   No.1 Thread: B 
>   No.1 Thread: A 
>   No.2 Thread: A 
>   No.2 Thread: C
>  No.2 Thread: B
>  No.3 Thread: A
>  No.3 Thread: C
>  No.3 Thread: B
>   No.4 Thread: C
>  No.4 Thread: B
>  No.4 Thread: A
>  No.5 Thread: A
>  No.5
>   Thread: B
> No.5 Thread: C

The characters A,B,C are displayed in a random order. Is this not what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: But then it prints three characters per second. I want it to print 1 character(thread) per second in a random order. If you notice when it prints after a while the order is same again.

Comment: IT'S happening so because your starting three threads at  a time. Just delete the other two threads . Then it will print just 1 character at a time

Answer (score 0):

I would use a semaphore.

I'd initialize the semaphore to have zero permits, and I'd make each of the three counting threads take one permit each time around the loop.  Finally, I'd have the main thread loop, adding one permit to the semaphore ever second until all of the threads have finished.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are trying to create what's called a race condition: The character that gets printed depends on the thread that gets there first. Now, because of this it is normal that three characters get printed simultaneously instead of one at a time. If it didn't, the order wouldn't be random anymore. What may work best is having the three threads shuffle up the order first by remembering the order in which each of them wants to print a character, then join the threads again and then print out the three characters from one of the threads. I'm by no means an expert on this but I think you need to put the code that appends the character to the string in a synchronised block, as well. A bit like this:

```
public class Number1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Printer printer=new Printer();
        try
        {
            Thread a = new Thread(new thread1("A", printer));
            Thread b = new Thread(new thread1("B", printer));
            Thread c = new Thread(new thread1("C", printer));
            a.start();
            b.start();
            c.start();
            a.join(1000);
            b.join(1000);
            c.join(1000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
                System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
}

class Printer
{
    int i=0;
    String[] strings=new String[3];
    //this method only prints and waits if it is called by the last of the three threads, to print all three
    //characters. So it returns true if the thread itself needs to wait three seconds. All three
    //threads must try to call it simultaneously so the order is random; to prevent errors though the method is synchronised.
    public synchronized boolean print(String s)
    {
        strings[i++]=s;
        if(i==3)
        {
            for(i=0; i<3; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(strings[i]);
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                }
            }
            i=0;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

class thread1 implements Runnable
{
    String character;
    Printer printer;
    public thread1(String a, Printer printer)
    {
        this.character = a;
        this.printer=printer;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        for(int i = 1;i<21;i++)
        {    
            if(printer.print("No."+i+" Thread: "+character))
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```